# adding a third-party linux kernel module with yocto

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver, yocto, kernel-module

I can't find how to add a 3rd-party `.ko` file into the `/lib/modules/.../extra` directory with Yocto.  I can find plenty of documentation how to build an out-of-tree module from source code.  But I only have a ready-to-go `.ko` file, not the source code.  Modifying the `hello-mod.bb` to a 'just install, do not make' makefile is not working.

BREF: could somebody point me to a good example how to do?

Answer (score 3):

```
SRC_URI += "file://module.ko"

do_install() {
    install -m 0644 module.ko ${D}/lib/modules/
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you have to build the module with yocto then you have to make a recipe as well. A nice explanation is given here:

[yocto manual](http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.2/kernel-manual/kernel-manual.html#incorporating-out-of-tree-modules)

Comment: as I was mentioning in my question, I do not have the source code.  So 'building' is not what I want to do.